# Windows phone 7 -- programmatically create the initial UI?

Tags: user-interface, windows-phone-7

I want to create the UI in code when the app starts up.  What would be the natural place for this code?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to put it in the page constructor right after the `InitializeComponent()` call. I don't see a need to do this since you have the XAML designer at hand anyway - it will eventually create a small performance overhead because you are building the page twice - once when it's loaded and the second time when you add additional components.

Comment: Yes, I would reiterate the point - Don't do anything at run time which you could do at design time!

Comment: I disagree about the overhead - I think the runtime would be *marginally* quicker if the construction the page in C# rather than in XAML. However, from a productivity and maintainability point of view, I totally agree with Dennis and Matt! The only time I can think of when I would want to start creating the UI in code is if there were a lot of conditionals which really didn't work well in XAML - but that's not your typical app?

Comment: I think the intent of the question is more like "I want to manually call `new MainPage()` rather than use the application manifest's default task"

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your intention is to have a total control of the application resources in this manner. You get one entry point, where you can initialize a view, as well as the other operational classes, that make your application tick.

So my answer would be this:

In App() initialize an IoC right a way.

Then let default code, such as `InitializeComponent()` do it's job. Remove `InitializePhoneApplication()` and insert your view initialization logic there.